# Clone div and its inner elements

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clone DIV and it's inner elements. How can I change the names of all inner elements? Also I have function calls on the radio buttons. I need to change the name of the function also.Here is my HTML code. I appreciate any help.

```
<div id="clonableDiv">
    <input id="radio_1" type="radio1" onclick="toggleNames1()" value="Yes" name="Yes">
    Yes
    <br>
    <input id="radio_2" type="radio1" onclick="toggleNames2()" value="No" name="No">
    No
    <div id="address">Address:</div>
    <div id="address1">
        <input id="address_1" class="textBox" type="text" maxlength="100" name="address_1">
    </div>
    <div id="country_select">
        Country:
        <select id="country_drop_1" name="country_drop_1" onchange="setCountry(this.selectedIndex)"> 
            <option value="-1"></option>
            <option value="USA">USA</option>
            <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to clone that div, update all the IDs and names and then insert the clone into the body:

```
var cloneCntr = 1;
function makeClone() {
    // clone the div
    var clone = $("#clonableDiv").clone(false);
    // change all id values to a new unique value by adding "_cloneX" to the end
    // where X is a number that increases each time you make a clone
    $("*", clone).add(clone).each(function() {
        if (this.id) {
            this.id = this.id + "_clone" + cloneCntr;
        }
        if (this.name) {
            this.name = this.name + "_clone" + cloneCntr;
        }
    });
    ++cloneCntr;
    $(document.body).append(clone);                         

}
```

To update the onclick handlers, you can just assign new values to them with `obj.onclick = fn;`.

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/r2RLw/.

Much of this fixup of the clone would not be needed if you didn't use ID values and only used class names, but if this is part of a form that is getting submitted so you need unique name values, then you will have to do this type of fixed after cloning.

Comment: How can I see the html after cloning? I did 'View source' but couldn't see the changed html markup.

Comment: They aren't in View Source because they aren't part of the source only the dynamic page.  You need to use a DOM Inspector like is built into Chrome, Opera or Safari (right-click on an element and select "Inspect Element") or install Firebug into Firefox.  Any of these will let you see the whole DOM hierarchy including all the cloned elements with the right-click/Inspect Element.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly this sounds like a huge headache that simply isn't worth it. Whenever I want to clone a large grouping of elements I stay away from using IDs and stick to using class identifiers. That way I can clone the entire collection of elements and uniquely identify them by their parent and following class hierarchy. For example:

```
<div class="obj_Template">
    <span class="obj_SomeSpanChild1">Access Me!</span
    <span class="obj_SomeSpanChild2"><div class="obj_CountryName">USA</div></span>
</div>

var second = $(".obj_Template").clone().removeClass("obj_Template").addClass("obj_SecondElement");
second.insertAfter($(".obj_Template));
```

Now you have two uniquely identifiable parent elements and you can use the same code to traverse them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cloneCounter = 1;
var c = $('#clonableDiv').clone();
$('input, select', c).each(function(){
  var newName = $(this).attr('name');
  newName += '_' + cloneCounter;
  $(this).attr('name', newName);
})
cloneCounter++;
$('body').append(c);
```

you can see a quick example I made here: http://jsfiddle.net/CQKpP/1/

Comment: I would like to use the counter so the names should change from '_2', '_3', '_4' etc. How can I do this? Thank you for you kind help.

Answer (score -2):

you can change the names in one of 2 ways:

1. get the innerHtml of the div, and do a replace on it with a clever regex
2. clone the div, iterate over its children and change their name attributes

both of these have their merits, but id suggest the 2nd in your case.

Comment: HTML is not regular, so Regex is not safe.

Comment: If we are talking in terms of absolutes, then you are right. But we are talking about THAT html up there, and i can write a regex that will work for THAT html and never cause any problems.